# TransitionEnd stacking events

Tags: jquery, webkit, css-transitions

When trying to do some slides for a mobile-page I run into a problem with transitions and transitionEnd

```
$(document).on('click', '#map_view', function () {
    var lpw = $('.list-page-wrap'), mpw = $('#map_view_page'), smb = $('.slide-me-back');
    lpw.css("-webkit-transform", "translate3d(100%, 0, 0)");
    lpw.one("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function () { mpw.css("-webkit-transform", "translate3d(0, 0, 0)"); console.log ("ERROR!!!!"); });
});

$(document).on('click', '#list_view', function () {
    var lpw = $('.list-page-wrap'), mpw = $('#map_view_page');
    mpw.css("-webkit-transform", "translate3d(100%, 0, 0)");
    mpw.one("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function () { lpw.css("-webkit-transform", "translate3d(0, 0, 0)"); });
});
```

in code above the

```
lpw.one("transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd MSTransitionEnd", function () { mpw.css("-webkit-transform", "translate3d(0, 0, 0)"); console.log ("ERROR!!!!"); });
```

line is triggered twice when clicking the the lower one

is there a workaround for this or a known issue?

Comment: A [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of this code with HTML would be very much helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I'm trying to add it atm but I don' really know how to add it as a mobile-page seeing as I have made it for mobile

Comment: ** Edit! **
jsfiddle doesn't seem to support transitions at all, do you have any other pages for me to upload it on?

Comment: uhm ... you sure? http://jsfiddle.net/rGECn/1/ works fine for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in another thread here, what I missed was:

```
$(this).off('webkitTransitionEnd transitionend msTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd');
```

thanks for the help though